# LinkedIn API v2 how to use r_basicprofile for fields?

Tags: linkedin-api

It's January 2019. I'm migrating to LinkedIn API v2, as LinkedIn requires.
My app has set up && been granted (by user clicks) these permissions shown in this picture.
[image]
The simplest API call is GET "/v2/me" with no extra query string, which returns data in this shape:

```
"{\"lastName\":{\"localized\":{\"en_US\":\"Jobs\"},\"preferredLocale\":{\"country\":\"US\",\"language\":\"en\"}},\"firstName\":{\"localized\":{\"en_US\":\"Steve\"},\"preferredLocale\":{\"country\":\"US\",\"language\":\"en\"}},\"profilePicture\":{\"displayImage\":\"urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:X9999XXXX5-XXx9-bye\"},\"id\":\"XyyyyXXXXX\"}"
```

But I wish to ask for more fields (all of which are allowed once I have `r_basicprofile` as mentioned https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/profile/basic-profile) by GET "/v2/me?fields=id,firstName,lastName,headline,profilePicture",
but received:

```
"{\"serviceErrorCode\":100,\"message\":\"not enough permissions to access field headline for GET /me\",\"status\":403}"
```

Indeed https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api did NOT say `/v2/me`
 can have query string like `?fields=id,firstName,lastName,headline,profilePicture`. If this query string is not allowed right now. what am I benefiting from `r_basicprofile`?

I have also tried GET "/v2/people/(id:{person ID})", which got

```
"{\"serviceErrorCode\":100,\"message\":\"Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/(id:XyyyyXXXXX)\",\"status\":403}"
```

Comment: This is tricky but I think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context states that r_basicprofile should no longer be used in API v2. The `r_liteprofile` is replacing it; `r_liteprofile` gives way fewer fields.

Answer (score 9):

Before 1st March You have to Move in V2
r_basicprofile is there because you can use this with V1 till 1st march 
after that this will automatically deleted

in V2 you have to use :

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

r_emailaddress for getting emailAddress - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

Comment: Where do you see in the documentation that r_basicprofile can't be used in V2 of API? I'm not saying you're wrong, I just can't find that mentioned in docs anywhere.

Comment: Never mind I see it now! If you have access to partner program you can still use r_basicprofile but otherwise you're correct you need to use r_liteprofile

Comment: Yes, You are correct at many place i already written for using r_basicprofile  you have to take permission from linkedin.  I mean need to access partnership 
 program.

Comment: So today it is 6th March 2019 and we still have the r_basicprofile permission. So if we cant use v1 anymore, why is r_basicprofile permission still there? Where does your information, that the permission should have been automatically deleted, come from?

Comment: Here they've documented that one needs to *"have applied and been approved for a LinkedIn Partner Program"*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile#profile-fields-available-with-linkedin-partner-programs

Comment: what about the headline?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context), in addition to updating your scope to `r_liteprofile`, you would have to change the API endpoint from `people/~:(id,firstName,lastName)` to `me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)` to get the basic profile details.